# Remove row from tree table in Vaadin

Tags: row, vaadin, treetable

I'm doing a project in Vaadin 7. 
In that I need to remove a row from Treetable.

I even couldn't find any way to remove any row from the Treetable.
I used removeItem(), But, can't get it done.

can anyone help me in this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time, it would be good if you show us your sourceode. Then we can say you what the misstake is and how to resolve it.

If you have a TreeTable then you can remove all items with *removeAllItems()* or single items with *removeItem(Object)*

Now, if you add a item on the TreeTable, you have to give this item a itemID what you can use later to find this again and delete this item.

```
final TreeTable     treeTable   = new TreeTable();
//...
treeTable.addItem(new Object[]{"value", "value", "value"}, 0);
treeTable.addItem(new Object[]{"value", "value", "value"}, 1);
treeTable.addItem(new Object[]{"value", "value", "value"}, 2);
//...
treeTable.removeItem(1);
```

This very small example will create 3 Items in the your treeTable with the ID´s *0*, *1* and *2*. After this it delete the Item with the ID *1*.

You can find [here](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Table.html#removeItem%28java.lang.Object%29) the Documentation about TreeTable and the method *removeItem()*.